# Curvature as infinitesimal holonomy via the path-ordered exponential formula

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-bundles, curvature, connections

Exercise 95 (page 247) in Baez & Muniain's Gauge Fields, Knots and Gravity asks us to prove the well-known formula:

$$v - v' = \epsilon^2 F_{\mu \nu} v + o(\epsilon^2)$$

where $v \in E_p$ is a vector in the vector bundle $E \to  M$ with a fixed connection, $v' \in E_p$ is the result of parallel transporting $v$ around a square of side $\epsilon$ in the $x^\mu$ - $x^\nu$ plane, and $F$ is the curvature tensor.

Specifically, the hint is to use the formula

$$ u(t) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \left[ (-1)^n \int_{t \geq t_1 \geq \cdots \geq t_n \geq 0} A(\gamma'(t_1)) \cdots A(\gamma'(t_n)) dt_n \cdots dt_1 \right] u $$

which expresses the parallel transport of $u(0) = 0$ along the curve $\gamma(t)$ (it's possible to use the path-ordering operator to write this formula as an exponential, but I believe this more explicit version is the one that'll be useful for computation), keeping only terms up to order $\epsilon^2$.

Due to the linearity of holonomy, I believe it's sufficient to establish the desired formula for $v = e_i$ (with respect to some local trivialization that I'm supposing already fixed).

For convenience I recall

$$ F_{\mu \nu} e_i = \left( \partial_\mu A^j_{\nu i} - \partial_\nu A^j_{\mu i} + A^j_{\mu k} A^k_{\nu i} - A^j_{\nu k} A^k_{\mu i} \right) e_j $$

Let's WLOG suppose $p = 0$, and let $e^1_i$ be the result of parallel transporting $e_i$ from the origin to the first corner of the square (at $x^\mu = \epsilon, x^\nu = 0$). In this case, $\gamma' = \partial_\mu$. To first order in the paralell transport formula, we get

$$ e^1_i \approx e_i - \int_{0}^{\epsilon} A_\mu(0, \ldots, t_1, \ldots, 0) e_i dt_1$$

where $t_i$ belongs to the $\mu$ component. We could go to second order, but we'd get terms of the form $A_\mu A_\mu$ which seems a step in the wrong direction. To deal with this integral, I thought of approximating

$$A_\mu(0, \ldots, t_1, \ldots, 0) \approx A_\mu(0) + t_1 \partial_\mu A_\mu(0) $$

The first term integrates to give $-\epsilon A_\mu(0) e_i = -\epsilon A^j_{\mu i} e_j$, and the second gives $-(\epsilon^2/2) \partial_\mu A_\mu$ -- despite it being of second order, since it contains $\partial_\mu A_\mu$ it also doesn't look like it's going well. So if we unashamedly ignore that we'd get something like

$$e_i^1 \approx e_i - \epsilon A^j_{\mu i} e_j$$

The main problem is that by following this stratagem I don't see how we can possibly get the crossed derivative terms that need to show up in the final formula. For the 'horizontal' sides (along the $\mu$ direction) the integrals will always involve $A_\mu$ terms, and Taylor expanding those operators will give rise to $\mu$ derivatives of $A_\mu$ -- mutatis mutandis for $\nu$.

This is all to say I feel lost on how to go about this computation. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I did this computation a few months back, and I kept terms involving $\epsilon^2$. You should always keep terms involving $\epsilon^2$ because as evident in the formula, the curvature is a second order effect, so we only ignore the terms involving $\epsilon^3$. In the end a whole bunch of cross terms will end up cancelling out, and you'll end up with the desired result (it was not a fun exercise). All I can say is be patient, do things diligently and pray for the best.

Comment: @peek-a-boo Were you using the same strategy of Taylor expanding $A$? Did you go to first or second order in the path-ordered exponential series?

Comment: yes, I did Taylor expand $A$, and I went second order for the series (I seem to have lost the work which I wrote on some scratch paper). Anyway, based on what you've written it seems you've only done the computation for the origin to the bottom right corner of the square. If you do the computation for the remaining edges of the square, the right terms should start appearing.

Comment: In the middle, some unwanted terms do appear, like $\frac{\epsilon^2}{2}\partial_{\mu}A_{\mu}(0)$, but they all cancel out eventually. As a side note: I actually found it helpful to consider parallel transport around a rectangle of side lengths $\epsilon$ and $\delta$, because then in the expansion, I would get terms like $\epsilon^2, \delta^2,\epsilon\delta$, and then having the slight distinction between the range of parameters for the $\mu$ and $\nu$ direction made it easier for me to detect certain algebraic mistakes. Not sure if this will necessarily help you though

Comment: @Pedro the answer to this question here might be helpful:  https://mathoverflow.net/questions/272253/reference-for-parallel-transport-around-loop-and-its-relation-to-curvature?rq=1

Comment: Here is one way to get curvature from holonomy. You can adapt it to your specific situation. https://deaneyang.github.io//blog/blog/math/differential-geometry/riemannian-geometry/2020/08/07/Holonomy.html